# MySQL statement pulling too many rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two data tables that I am querying using an Inner Join statement. one of the tables pulls daily company stock information and consequently has a row for each company for each day the market is open. The other table holds qualitative data about the company and only has one row per company.

I am trying to pull the most recent stock information and pair it with the qualitative company information in an HTML table. I have everything working except that it is still pulling every row of daily info for the company rather than the most recent.

Can someone assist with this query?:

```
$query = "SELECT daily_info.Day, 
daily_info.Prev_close, 
stocks.Symbol, 
stocks.Company, 
stocks.Description 
FROM daily_info 
INNER JOIN stocks ON daily_info.Symbol = stocks.Symbol 
ORDER BY daily_info.Day, stocks.Company LIMIT 43
"; 

Example: 
Table 1: Daily_info
Day       |  Symbol  |  Company    |  Prev Close
06/15/14  |  CRM     |  Salesforce |  $52.34
06/15/14  |  AMZN    |  Amazon     |  $342.65
06/16/15  |  CRM     |  Salesforce |  $55.24
06/16/14  |  AMZN    |  Amazon     |  $349.64



Table 2: Stock
Symbol  |  Company           | Description
CRM     |  Salesforce.com    | This is a cloud based CRM company
AMZN    |  Amazon.com        | This is an ecommerce company


Output:
Company        |  Symbol   |  Prev Close    |   Description
Amazon.com     |  AMZN     |  $349.64       | This is an ecommerce company 
Salesforce.com |  CRM      |  $55.24        | This is a cloud based CRM company
```

Comment: Why is there a `LIMIT 43` if you just want to pull one row?

Comment: To get the most recent stock information, you will need a column that stores the datetime of the stock information, and `order by` that column in `DESC` and do a `LIMIT 1`

Comment: There are 43 stocks that I want to pull info for. I want to pull the most recent information for those 43. Instead it is returning every row in the daily_info table.

Comment: This reference page should help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @Jeremy in that case, you need to `GROUP BY` the stocks.symbol. It would be better to show example of the data for SO community to review your code.

Comment: @Sky... that's exactly what I'm doing no? daily_info.Day is the date of the stock price and then I am ordering by it.

Comment: @Jeremy there's no sample of the current output nor any information about the columns, it's hard for us to do much, we can only guess the data base on the name. daily_info.Day column gave me brain cancer when I'm trying to figure out what the data is.

Comment: I have updated the info with a sample of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MySQL supports LAG functions so you'll need to do a subquery to get the last date for each Symbol, then INNER join on that result. Something like this should work:

```
 $query = "
    SELECT l.Company, l.Symbol, l.Prev_Close, r2.Description
    FROM Daily_info as l
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Symbol, MAX(Prev_close) as last_date FROM Daily_info GROUP BY Symbol) AS r
    ON (l.Symbol=r.Symbol AND l.Prev_close=r.last_date)
    INNER JOIN Stock as r2
    ON (l.Symbol=r2.Symbol)
    ";
```